# HoverTool on Bokeh: Time format issue (date do not appear correctly) x axis from datetime DF column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

Here the code I wrote.
I took the data from pandas DF (not pasted here).
The x values are from DF index columns that is a DateTime column.
The issue that I want to resolve is in line:

TOOLTIPS = [("index", "$index"),("(Time,Temperature)", "($x, $y)"),]

when I have to change the $x format to a correct format in order to see the the time format in the hover window on the bokeh plot.

see the python code

```
import datetime as dt
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, BooleanFilter
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter



x=df_bases.index

y0=df_bases["base_1"]
y1=df_bases["base_5"]
y2=df_bases["base_12"]



# output to static HTML file
output_file("temperatures from thermocouples.html")



# add some renderers

output_file("Thermocouples temperature.html", title="Thermocouples temperature")

TOOLTIPS = [("index", "$index"),("(Time,Temperature)", "($x, $y)"),]


# create a new plot with a datetime axis type
p = figure( tooltips=TOOLTIPS , plot_width=1250, plot_height=580, x_axis_type="datetime", x_axis_label='Time', 
           y_axis_label='Temperature [°C]', title="Thermocouples temperature") 


p.line(x, y0, legend="thermocouple 1", line_width=1 , color='navy', alpha=1)
p.line(x, y1, legend="thermocouple 5", color="green")
p.line(x, y2, legend="thermocouple 12", line_width=1 , color='orange', alpha=1)#, line_dash="4 4")

p.border_fill_color = "whitesmoke"


p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
    microseconds = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'],
    milliseconds = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'],
    seconds = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    minsec = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    minutes = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    hourmin = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    hours=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    days=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    months=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
    years=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
)


p.title.align = 'center'





# create a column data source for the plots to share
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y0=y0, y1=y1, y2=y2))

# create a view of the source for one plot to use
view = CDSView(source=source)




# show the results
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of Bokeh 1.2) the hover tool does not have any "always on" mode It only hovers in response to hit-testing glyphs that are added to the plot. Additionally there is no way to apply formatting to "special vars" like `$x` (that will be possible starting in Bokeh 2.0). Custom formatters can only be applied to hover tooltips for data columns. Given that, my best suggestion is to switch to using `@x`instead (which interrogates the "x" data column, not the x mouse position". If you do that, you can use all the techniques in the [Formatting Tooltip Fields](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields) section of the docs.

Since you did not provide a *complete* example (no data to run), I can only provide partial untested suggestions:

```
# use @x{%F} to specify the %F datetime format (or choose another) for the x column
TOOLTIPS = [("index", "$index"),("(Time,Temperature)", "(@x{%F}, $y)")]

# tell bokeh to use the "datetime" formatter for the x column
p.hover.formatters = {'x': 'datetime'}

# just a suggestion, often useful for timeseries plots
p.hover.mode = 'vline'
```